# useRef's data is delayed when brought up by useImperativeHandle

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I am using useImperativeHandle from Input Component to pass data of ref to Login Component but I run into a problem when data of emailInputRef is delayed compared to data of inputRef

```
const Login = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isvalid, setIsValid] = useState(true);

  const emailInputRef = useRef();
  const passwordInputRef = useRef();

  const email = emailInputRef.current?.value;
  const password = passwordInputRef.current?.value;

  console.log("data in login: ", email, password);

  const submitHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    setIsValid((prevState) => !prevState);

    // return router.push("/dashboard");
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.login}>
      <div className={styles.card}>
        <p className={styles["signin-label"]}>Log In</p>
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className={styles["signin-form"]}>
          <Input
            ref={emailInputRef}
            name="email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
          />
          <p className={styles["none-display"]}>Please enter a valid email.</p>
          <Input
            ref={passwordInputRef}
            name="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
          />
          <p className={isvalid ? styles["none-display"] : ""}>
            Incorrect Email or Password.
          </p>
          <Button>Log In</Button>
        </form>
        <div className={styles["sign-up"]}>
          <p>Need an account?</p>
          <Link href="/signup">Sign up now.</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const Input = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  console.log("data in input " + inputRef.current?.value);

  const getValue = () => {
    return inputRef.current?.value;
  };

  const clear = () => {
    return (inputRef.current.value = "");
  };

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => {
      return {
        value: getValue(),
        clear,
      };
    },
    [getValue(), clear]
  );

  return (
    <div className={styles["input-container"]}>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        name={props.name}
        type={props.type}
        className={styles.input}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        required
      />
      <label className={styles.label}>{props.placeholder}</label>
    </div>
  );
});
```

[here is the data output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqqXT.png)

I don't know what the problem is. I don't want to use useState because I don't want my component re-render whenever the input changes. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `email` and `password` values are undefined in the `submitHandler` exactly because your `Login` component never re-rerenders since the initial render until you change its state with `setIsValid`.

There is nothing really wrong with re-rendering the `Login` component on each keystroke, and you are not going to see any noticeable performance penalties unless you are dealing with extensively large form.

Furthermore, in your implementation of the imperative handler, you are capturing the input value at the time the `useImperativeHandle` runs and it's not going to reflect current value anyway.

Here are 2 implementation options I can recommend in your case:

**1) Controlled inputs**

In this case the `Login` component re-renders on each keystroke, but the added bonus is you can perform validation as the user types.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Input from "./Input";

export default function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = React.useState(true);

  const clear = () => {
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
  };

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log({ email, password });

    setIsValid((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <form noValidate onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <p>Log In</p>

      <Input
        name="email"
        type="email"
        label="Email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
      />

      <Input
        name="password"
        type="password"
        label="Password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
      />

      {!isValid && <p>Incorrect Email or Password.</p>}

      <button type="submit">Log In</button>

      <button type="button" onClick={clear}>Clear</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

```js
export default function Input({
  type,
  name,
  label,
  value,
  required,
  onChange,
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <input
        name={name}
        type={type}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        required={required}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**2) Uncontrolled inputs**

In this case the `Login` component does not re-rerender on each keystroke, and you can validate user input only when the form gets submitted.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Input from "./Input";

export default function Login() {
  const emailRef = React.useRef(null);
  const passwordRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = React.useState(true);

  const clear = () => {
    emailRef.current.value = "";
    passwordRef.current.value = "";
  };

  const onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    const email = formData.get("email");
    const password = formData.get("password");

    console.log({ email, password });

    // or alternatively
    // console.log({
    //   email: emailRef.current.value,
    //   password: passwordRef.current.value,
    // });

    setIsValid((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <form noValidate onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <p>Log In</p>

      <Input ref={emailRef} name="email" type="email" label="Email" />

      <Input
        ref={passwordRef}
        name="password"
        type="password"
        label="Password"
      />

      {!isValid && <p>Incorrect Email or Password.</p>}

      <button type="submit">Log In</button>

      <button type="button" onClick={clear}>
        Clear
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

```js
import * as React from "react";

export default React.forwardRef(function Input(
  { type, name, label, required },
  ref,
) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <input ref={ref} name={name} type={type} required={required} />
    </div>
  );
});
```

However, if you do need to use `useImperativeHandle` for some other reasons not outlined in your original question, you can implement something along these lines:

```js
useImperativeHandle(
  ref,
  () => ({
    getValue: () => inputRef.current.value,
    clear: () => (inputRef.current.value = ""),
  }),
  []
);
```